# overloading operators for std::vector and namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, stdvector

I'm overloading operator << for vector:

```
namespace A {
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    ofs << vec.size() << std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) ofs << vec[i] << std::endl;
    return ofs;
}
}
```

When then I try to use this operator in another **namespace B**, it does not compile, saying it can't find proper operator overload. Well, this is more or less expected. But if I move this definition to global namespace, it does not compile either. Only if I put operator into **namespace B**, it works.

Does it mean that I need to copy this operator into every namespace I want to use it? Or am I just making some mistake here?

UPD. I found why and when it gives error with global namespace:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    ofs << vec.size() << std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) ofs << vec[i] << std::endl;
    return ofs;
}

namespace B{
struct C{
int i;
};
//If one comments next line, code compiles.
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, const C& c) {ofs << c.i << '\n'; return ofs;}

void f() {
   std::vector<int> vec; vec.push_back(3);
   std::cout << vec; //mistake!
}
}
```

I can avoid such mistakes by puting all operators to global namespace. However it's considered a bad practice, isn't it? So you what would you think is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: By "this isn't the problem" you mean that I should just copy it everywhere I use it?

Comment: By "this isn't the problem" I mean that my comment doesn't address the question that you asked.

Comment: When you say it does not compile, please provide error message and reduce your example to the smallest possible complete way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: in namespace A, I can see that, but [not in the global namespace](http://ideone.com/Ar8RTK). I think you've left something out of the question. A `std::vector<class_that_does_not_have_stream_operator>`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that I made syntax mistake, as now I can't reproduce my problem. It really works with global namespace. I'm very sorry for wasting your time, excuse me please.

Comment: UPD! I found the source of the mistake (question edited) so there is still a problem to deal with.

Comment: To understand what's happening, [start here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup). To solve your problem while keeping things in namespaces as you want, a [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) will help.

Comment: Thanks! Using-declaration is the answer.